# バッジの説明文に不要なピリオドが混じっている

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, バッジ

### 不具合事象

各バッジの説明文ページで、文末に不要なピリオドがある場合があります。以下は[支配人](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/steward)、[師匠](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/18/guru)、[篤志家](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/48/altruist)バッジの説明文のスクリーンショットと引用文です：

- [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

  > レビュータスクを 1,000 件以上完了しました。このバッジは、レビュー 1 種類につき何回でも獲得できます。. このバッジは何回も獲得できます。
- [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

  > 回答が承認され、スコア 40 以上を獲得した. このバッジは何回も獲得できます。
- [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

  > 別のユーザーの質問に初めて手動で懸賞を授与した.

これらの説明文を見ると、一見ピリオドは句点の代わりに見えます。しかし句点とピリオドが同時に使われている箇所や、句点が使われている箇所があり、「ピリオドが文末に挿入されることがある」という特徴以外に一貫性がありません。

### 提案

文章内の不要なピリオドは、スクリーンリーダーが文章を読み上げる際の雑音になる可能性があるため、ピリオドの削除と句点への置き換えを提案します。一方で、これらのピリオドは ja.traducir.win 上の文字列に存在しないようです。

たとえば支配人バッジの説明文に関する文字列は、 ja.traducir.win に 2 つあります（[1 つ目](https://ja.traducir.win/strings/14537)、[2 つ目](https://ja.traducir.win/strings/3965)）。しかし、いずれの翻訳された文字列にもピリオドは含まれていません。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「このバッジは何回も取得できます」の部分などは複数のバッジで使われる文面なので、バッジの説明文は複数の翻訳文字列に分割されたものが表示の際に連結されています。

そして現状では (翻訳されることを考慮されずに) **ピリオドが表示時に追加されている** のでおかしな事になっているようです。

対応としては、翻訳前の時点で対象文字列にもきちんとピリオドを含めてもらい、各言語で翻訳できる形にしてもらうのがよさそうです。(スタッフによる対応が必要です)

**現状:**

```
First bounty you offer on another person's question
```

**改善案:**

```
First bounty you offer on another person's question.
```

Answer (score 3):

[こちらのストリングを](https://ja.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=badgeDescriptionHtml&ignoredStatus=2)編集してください。問題はこれで解決できるはずです。